# Is the machine code generated by JIT same for two different systems?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jit, machine-code

I'm a C# beginner,
Is the machine code generated by the JIT in run time is same for the two different systems having exactly same configuration?

Comment: You're working assumption should be "No".  The original intent was that the JIT could, among other things, optimize based on actual execution patterns.  In other words, it's entirely possible the machine code might even be different from run to run, not just from machine to machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [a nice article](http://24x7aspnet.blogspot.com/2009/10/just-in-time-jit-compiler-in.html) about your question. It's rather long, so I've extracted the most essential parts:

- The compilation can be optimized to the targeted CPU and the operating system model where the application runs. For example JIT can choose SSE2 CPU instructions when it detects that the CPU supports them.
- The system is able to collect statistics about how the program is actually running in the environment it is in, and it can rearrange and recompile for optimum performance.

So indeed, the disassembly may differ not only across platforms, but also across runs on the same system.